# Use table type from one store to second one

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my first stored procedure I have Table type like

```
@EmployeeGuidIdTableType  [Helper].[GuidIdTableType] READONLY
```

Then I send this table to another procedure like:

```
  EXEC [usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation]
                   @EmployeeGuidIdTableType = @EmployeeGuidIdTableType
```

Then into second stored procedure I receive it as parameter like:

```
 @EmployeeGuidIdTableType  [Helper].[GuidIdTableType] READONLY
```

and finally I want to use it into where clause of this insert like:

```
 INSERT INTO @TaskStatusAuditToUseTable
                 SELECT
                       [TS].[TaskStatusAuditId]
                     , [TS].[Date]
                     , [TS].[EmpGuid]
                     , [TS].[TaskStatusName]
                     , [TS].[TaskTypeName]
                     , [TS].[TaskId]
                       FROM [TaskStatusAudit] AS [TS]
                           INNER JOIN [Task] AS [T] ON [TS].[TaskId] = [T].[TaskId]
                       WHERE(@TaskId IS NULL
                            OR @TaskId = [TS].[TaskId])

                        AND (@EmployeeGuidIdTableType IS NULL                                                                                    
                       OR [TS].[EmpGuid] IN (SELECT [Id] 
                      FROM @EmployeeGuidIdTableType                                                                                      
                     WHERE [TS].[EmpGuid] = @EmployeeGuidIdTableType))
```

But `@EmployeeGuidIdTableType` is marked in red and throw:

> Must declare the scalar variable `@EmployeeGuidIdTableType`

What am I doing wrong? I can declare it as:

```
 DECLARE @GuidIdTableTypeValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM @EmployeeGuidIdTableType)
```

and use `@GuidIdTableTypeValue` but the idea of table type is to execute multiple inserts but if I declare as:

```
 DECLARE @GuidIdTableTypeValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT [Id] FROM @EmployeeGuidIdTableType)
```

And I execute stored procedure I get

> Procedure usp_TaskStatus_Time_Calculation,
>   Line 24 [Batch Start Line 191] Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: I think the real issue is you don't fully grasp how table valued parameters work. They are just another table. You should use an inner join instead of trying to force your table into a scalar variable.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to write a comparison operator that compares a table with a scalar value, which is not possible.   The scalar value contains a single value, and the table contains multiple rows, so it's not possible to compare them with an equals sign like you're doing.

Did you maybe mean to compare them with the IN() operator?   Your question isn't clear about what result you're trying to acheive.

Comment: Yes, I want co compare with IN operator, that's the real desire task